# HTTP connection fails with certain website on API 16, but not API 10

Tags: android, xml, api, http, url

I am having trouble with an HTTP connection failing when run on API 16, but works fine on API 10.  Other website connections execute properly with the same code, so it is an issue with this website in particular.  The connection is created and read in with the following code:  (UPDATED 02/04/14 to include the entire test program)

```
package com.example.test2;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getData(View view) {    
    new TaskGetDir().execute(); 
}




public class TaskGetDir extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String gpx_url = "http://gpx.geotags.com/cgi-bin/gpx.cgi?saddr=Boston,MA%s&daddr=NewYork,NY%s";
    String doc_gpx = "";

    try {

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(gpx_url).openConnection();

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");        
        char[] buffer = new char[512];
        reader.read(buffer);
        doc_gpx = new String(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return doc_gpx;

}


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   

        TextView out_loc1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_out);           
        out_loc1.setText(result.toString());

    }

}

}
```

The code properly extracts 512 characters into the buffer and displays through textView on API10, but it crashes with API 16.  The failure occurs during the conn.getContent() call. The logcat logging is shown below:

```
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:156)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:311)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendEncoded(UriCodec.java:114)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendPartiallyEncoded(UriCodec.java:142)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URLStreamHandler.java:281)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.net.URL.toURILenient(URL.java:510)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.<init>(HttpEngine.java:195)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:256)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:78)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:190)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at com.example.test.MainActivity$TaskGetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at com.example.test.MainActivity$TaskGetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-31 07:42:34.096: E/AndroidRuntime(11036):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

When this website is entered into a browser window, a file is prompted to download automatically, and the connection is then terminated from the server side.  It returns directions in xml format with lat/lon attributes that I would like to extract.  My theory is that the different APIs are handling this attempted download differently.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you showing us the complete code? This is a very unusual way of using `HttpURLConnection`. You'd better search for good examples or use an [abstraction library for HTTP requests](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background). At least you should remove `conn.getContent()` and give the `InputStream` directly to your XML parser.

Comment: I have updated the code above to show the entire test program.  I removed the conn.getContent() call and am seeing identical results.  It displays the buffer just fine on the emulator, but crashes on the phone (API 16) at the conn.getInputStream() call. I am using similar code to the example found here:[link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html). If I use a different url, for example "https://www.google.com", it connects fine on both devices and displays the contents. It seems to be an issue with establishing a connection to this particular site with API16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it has something to do with improperly encoded URL.

I tried it with my own HTTP Client ([DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/)):

```java
public void testDownloadGpx() throws Exception {

    Webb webb = Webb.create();
    Response<String> response = webb
            .get("http://gpx.geotags.com/cgi-bin/gpx.cgi")
            .param("saddr", "Boston,MA%s")
            .param("daddr", "NewYork,NY%s")
            .asString();

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
    assertNotNull(response.getBody());
    assertTrue(response.getBody().contains("Turn right to stay on Tremont"));
}

// the same request in a shorter form
public void testDownloadGpxShort() throws Exception {

    Webb webb = Webb.create();
    String xml = webb
            .get("http://gpx.geotags.com/cgi-bin/gpx.cgi")
            .param("saddr", "Boston,MA%s")
            .param("daddr", "NewYork,NY%s")
            .asString()
            .getBody();

    assertTrue(xml.contains("Turn right to stay on Tremont"));
}
```

In the debugger I can see that the URL is encoded like this:

```
http://.../gpx.cgi?saddr=Boston%2CMA%25s&daddr=NewYork%2CNY%25s
```

As your stacktrace shows that it's crashing in creating the URL, this could be the problem.
Try it with the above URL, please. I hope it works.

Comment: Yes, this URL works fine. Out of curiosity, any idea why the improperly encoded URL works with API 10 but not with API 16.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I suppose this is a bug in the newer implementation. I'd have to look at the source code of Android. Later...